# Merging MySQL and XML data together and sorting them

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I'm looking for a way to merge MySQL and XML data both together, so I can order them then by timestamp. The ideal situation would be something like:

```sql
SELECT timestamp, title
FROM news
UNION ALL
SELECT timestamp, title 
FROM xmlsource('local.xml')
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Is something like this possible? Or is their any other way to merge both data sources and sorting them? Thank you for any pointers in the right direction.

Comment: maybe loading this xml in temporary table?

Comment: i've thought about that, but i have hunderds of dynamic pages with different XML feeds and also dozens of users using them at the same time.. So a temporary table looks not like an option (or i have to make hunderds of them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how efficient will this be, but you can test that yourself. Here it is:

```
<?php
$sql = 'SELECT timestamp, title FROM news ORDER BY timestamp DESC';
$run = mysql_query( $sql, $link );

$result = array();
if( $run && mysql_num_rows( $run ) ) {
    while( ( $fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc( $run ) ) !== false ) {
        $time = $fetch[ 'timestamp' ];
        $title = htmlspecialchars( $fetch[ 'title' ], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8' );

        $result[ $time ][] = $title;
        // this is an array, in case multiple title have same timestamp.
    }
}

$xml = simplexml_load_file( 'local.xml' );
$xpath = $xml->xpath( '//story' );

foreach( $xpath as $story ) {
    $time = $story->time;
    $title = (string) $story->headline;

    $result[ $time ][] = $title; // append this to the results array.
}

// sort by timestamp ascending
arsort( $result );
?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this! Using a php array to merge all different sources was a big pointer in the right direction. I did make one general array `$thearray=array();`, and using array_push filled it with all variabels needed. The first field needed is a UNIX timestamp. `array_push($thearray, array ("unixtime" => $time, "story" => $story));`, using `rsort($thearray);` everything i wanted was done :)